# Is it safe to assume that everything happened in a constructor is visible to threads running methods after object initialization?

Tags: java, jvm, java-memory-model, jls

Lets have the following class:

```java
public class MyClass {
  private final List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(); //Not a thread-safe thing

  // Called on thread 1
  MyClass() {
    myList.add("foo");
  }

  // Called on thread 2
  void add(String data) {
    myList.add(data);
  }
}
```

Is it well-formed or not?

I was only able to find this:

> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

That means "thread 2" must see `ArrayList`, but may or may not see its content, right?

In other words, is it possible to have the following order:

T1: Creates `MyClass` along with `ArrayList`

T2: Accesses `ArrayList`

T1: Adds "foo" to the list

Comment: The order you gave is not possible. A constructor call is a synchronous process. Thus, `T1` does not have the possibility to set a reference to the (partially initialized) object so `T2` can read it.

Comment: Thank you, @Turing85 . Which JLS section says this? I only see guarantees about final fields

Comment: I do not fully understand the question. If `T1` wants to share some object with `T2`, it needs to write that object's reference to a shared variable. This means an assignment, e.g. `sharedVariable = new Foo();`. This guarantees that the `Foo`-object is fully constructed before its reference is assigned to `sharedVariable`.

Comment: How do you pass a link to the object from T1 to T2? For example, if it is a volatile field, then write and read to it would create a happens-before relationship according to JVM that guarantees visibility of all previous changes including adding foo

Comment: I'm with gdomo.  `myList` doesn't matter here.  We must know how you pass the reference to `MyClass` to T2 or we can't say if it's safe or not.  You need to show us that code.  *Assuming* T2 has a reference, then yes it can call `add()` safely (that's because the field is `final`).  However the call to `add()` may not be visible to any *other* thread in the system (including T1) because it is unsynchronized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thinking is incorrect. It's a sensible line of thought, but, this section of the JMM ([JMM §17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)):

> It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.

Disagrees with the analysis. So, assuming you adhere to the rules set forth in that section of the JMM, which is:

*Do not let the `this` ref escape from the constructor. e.g. if the constructor does `someStaticField = this;` or `someOtherThing.hereYouGo(this);`, any code that uses that `this` reference does not get the guarantee.*

Then not only are the direct values safe (as in, for primitives, the value, and for objects, the reference (i.e. the pointer)), but so are that object's fields / that array's slots. "safe" here means: Any code that refers to it (other than via the above exception where you don't get this safety) cannot observe any of the `final` fields in a state as it was before the constructor *finishes*.

Hence, your snippet is well-formed.

Note of course that the act of assigning the value of a constructor call is, itself, not covered by any of this. Hence:

```
class Example {
  MyObject c;

  void codeInThread1() {
    c = new MyObject();
  }

  void codeInThread2() {
    System.out.println(c);
  }
}
```

May result in thread 2 printing `null` (because `c` is observed as `null` by thread 2), *even if* other effects the code has clearly indicates thread1 has progressed well past `c = new MyObject();`. The JMM does not guarantee that one thread's writes are observed by another thread unless a Happens-Before relationship is established.

However, the JVM does guarantee no sheared writes for object refs and a certain consistency: There are only 2 things that can be observed by thread 2. EITHER `null`, OR a fully initialized object, i.e., no state as it was *before* the constructor finished can be observed by thread 2.

Comment: Why do you keep the wrong section at the end? It’s easy for readers to miss the smaller clarifying section. Besides that, the entire Q&A is dubious The extra guarantees for `final` fields are only relevant if the object is incorrectly exchanged between the threads. But if we assume that the two threads are not using correct synchronization, we can not assume the `add` call to work properly, as it is a mutation after the construction requiring a correct external synchronization, as `ArrayList` is not thread safe. So in either case, correct use or not, the `final` field guarantees are irrelevant

Comment: @Holger Do you think the answer would be improved if I just delete `Hold On!` and everything that follows?

Answer (score 3):

The "Hold on!" part of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795786) requires correction.

It's assumed there that the inner state of the object, stored in a final field, is guaranteed by the JMM to be visible in other threads at least as up-to-date as it was *when the final field was assigned* inside the constructor.

But actually, the JMM guarantees that the inner state will be as up-to-date as *at the end of the constructor*, where the final field was assigned.

The reason for the confusion is [the following sentence in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1):

> It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.

The quote above can be interpreted both ways because it's a human-friendly text.
To find out precisely what is guaranteed we need to look at the actual rules (which the quote above describes in a human-friendly way): [17.5.1. Semantics of final Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1).
Let's apply these rules to our example (notice the names of the actions given in the comments).

```java
public class MyClass {

  final List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

  MyClass() {
    myList.add("foo"); // w (internal write, e.g. myList.size=1)
    // f (freeze action which happens at the end of constructor)
  }

  void add(String data) {
    myList.add(data); // r1 (read of final field 'o.myList') and r2 (internal read, e.g. myList.size))
  }

  static MyClass o;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    var thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
      o = new MyClass(); // a (publication of the object in thread1)
    });
    var thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
      o.add("test"); // r0 (read of the published object in thread2)
    });
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
  }
}
```

With this action names we can use the following rule from the JLS:

> Given a write *w*, a freeze *f*, an action *a* (that is not a read of a `final` field), a read *r<sub>1</sub>* of the final field frozen by *f*, and a read *r<sub>2</sub>* such that *hb(w, f)*, *hb(f, a)*, *mc(a, r<sub>1</sub>)*, and *dereferences(r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>2</sub>)*, then when determining which values can be seen by *r<sub>2</sub>*, we consider *hb(w, r<sub>2</sub>)*. (This *happens-before* ordering does not transitively close with other *happens-before* orderings.)

As you can see, *w* (the write `o.myList.size=1` inside `MyClass()` in thread1) *happens-before** *r2* (the read of `o.myList.size` in thread2).
As a result, the JMM guarantees that thread2 sees inner state of `o.myList` as it was at the end of the constructor in thread1.

You can apply the same logic to any other inner field (at any depth) of the `o.myList` object.

For more info about the JMM `final` guarantees I would recommend [this presentation by Vladimir Sitnikov](https://www.slideshare.net/VladimirSitnikv/final-field-semantics).

---

P.S. it's worth noting that *freeze* happens at the end of the constructor that writes into the final field:

> Let *o* be an object, and *c* be a constructor for *o* in which a `final` field *f* is written. A *freeze* action on `final` field *f* of *o* takes place when *c* exits, either normally or abruptly.
>
> Note that if one constructor invokes another constructor, and the invoked constructor sets a `final` field, the freeze for the `final` field takes place at the end of the invoked constructor.

this means in the following example thread2 may see `myList` as empty, because `freeze` happens at the end of `private MyClass() {}` constructor:

```java
public class MyClass {

  final List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

  private MyClass() {}

  // in thread1
  MyClass(String str) {
    this();
    myList.add(str);
  }

  // in thread2
  void add(String data) {
    myList.add(data);
  }
}
```

Finally, those, who are curious about which of the object's constructors execute field initializers, should read [12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).